# How to play music in app from itunes library?

Tags: objective-c, ios

I need to play songs from iPod library in my ios application. How should I do this? Help me please

Answer (score 8, accepted):

See the [iPod Library Access Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Audio/Conceptual/iPodLibraryAccess_Guide/Introduction/Introduction.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008765).

> iPod library access lets your application play a user’s songs, audio books, and audio podcasts. The API design makes basic playback very simple while also supporting advanced searching and playback control.

Comment: thank you! do you have any examples of (music) apps that use this API?